# Make dropdown visible only when function is called

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying make the drop-down visible only when something is entered in the search bar.Otherwise it stays collapsed.  Following is my code

```js
function mysearchFunction() {
  var input, upperCase, ul, li, x, i, ax;
  input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
  upperCase = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    x = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(upperCase) === 0) {
      li[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      li[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myList li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mysearchInput" onkeyup="mysearchFunction()" placeholder="Search..">
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Antartica</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the JS, I am trying to make only content that needs to be displayed as visible. Kindly guide me where I am going wrong. No content is currently being displayed. It is staying collapsed.

Comment: I would suggest setting this up in a jsFiddle or another active coding platform so we can actually see your working code and help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated the css selector: `#myList li`, you were hiding all the links.

```js
function mysearchFunction() {
  var input, upperCase, ul, li, x, i, ax;
  input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
  upperCase = input.value.toUpperCase();
  //console.log(upperCase);
  ul = document.getElementById("myList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    x = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(upperCase) == 0 && upperCase !== '') {
      li[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      li[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myList li {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mysearchInput" onkeyup="mysearchFunction()" placeholder="Search..">
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Antartica</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you bhansa for the edit and your answer. However by doing this it is working only for the first time. It is not going back to collapse when search bar is empty.

Comment: but why are you checking for `=== 0` I think you can solve it by using `=== -1` as no index will return -1.

Comment: you are right. I think that is one of the way to do it. However if I check for -1 and I type "e". It will return America and Europe too. As both contain "e".

Comment: I just added a check for empty string, check the updated solution. If it works feel free to upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. Works perfectly and an elegant solution.

Comment: Happy to help :)